# Как заставить php открыть файл?

Tags: php

Скрипт

```
<?
  $file = function.fopen("file.txt","r");
  if(!file)
  {
      echo("Ошибка открытия файла");
  }
?>
```

Выдает в браузере ошибку

> `Warning: fopen(file.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\www\site1\htdocs\dir.php on line 13`

Answer (score 1):

=)

```
<?
if(file_exists("file.txt")){
  $file = fopen("file.txt","r"); //для начала, убираем function. Кроме того, у файла должны быть выставлены права на чтение.
 }else{
      echo("Ошибка открытия файла: файл не существует");
    }
?>
```

Comment: <b>No such file or directory</b> помоему тут проблема именно в этом ^^

Comment: Убрал, и добавилась еще одна ошибка, выводимая браузером.

>`Warning: fopen(file.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\www\site1\htdocs\dir.php on line 10`

>`Notice: Use of undefined constant file - assumed 'file' in C:\www\site1\htdocs\dir.php on line 11`

Comment: Короче гуглите о функции, это раз, ошибка по поводу глобальной переменной<br>
<pre><code>
if(!file) // у вас тут file а надо $file кагбы ^^
    {
      echo("Ошибка открытия файла");
    }
</pre></code><br>
Совсем забыл - что вы подразумеваете, когда пишите <b>ошибка выводимая бразером? ^^</b><br>

@Knes, тут в путе проблема, а не в правах. Может и с правами, но чтобы это узнать, надо путь правильно прописать для начала :)

Comment: С вашим скриптиком пишет "Ошибка открытия файла: файл не существует".
Права на чтение файла указал.

Comment: Права вы указали, но вот досада - указать <b>ПУТЬ</b> так и не смогли ^^<br>
Кароче гуглите на тему `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, возможно, вас осенит.

Comment: Путь прописал `$file = fopen("C:\www\site1\htdocs\file.txt","r");`. Пишет:
>Warning: fopen(C:\www\site1\htdocsile.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\www\site1\htdocs\dir.php on line 11

Но (`file_exists("file.txt")`) возвращает `true`. Уже не все так безнадёжно!
Так понимаю, что проблема в том, что скрипту не удается достучатся до `file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $file = function.fopen("file.txt","r");
```

Вы уверены в том, что это **php**? ^^
По сабжу - ошибка говорит о том что файла не существует(и не мудрено вы вообще не прописали путь...), т.е. должно быть что-то типа:

```
    $file = fopen( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/file.txt', 'r' );
```

Comment: Это php. Только function указал ради эксперимента. Без function тоже не работает. Говорит что-то вроде такого файла не существует. Пробовал прописывать путь примерно такого вида `С:/www/file.txt`.

Comment: Путь всегда прописывайте относительно корня, корень сервера это `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, вбейте эту "магическую" переменную в гугл и будет вам счастье...<br>
<b>С:/www/file.txt</b> - это в мэм, однозначно ^^

Comment: эм, простите, а что не так с С:/www/file.txt ? То что слеши обратные ?

Comment: слеши и в другую сторону пробовал. файл может не открываться из за настроек сервера?

Comment: То что так писать это мягко говоря, как бы так поточнее выразится...<br>
Ужасно чтоли :)

Comment: у вас странные критерии ужастности